# Linq: Join vs Include/ThenInclude in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, linq, entity-framework-core

I am working on a project with SQL Server and EF Core v3.

I have 4 tables related to each other. Here are my tables schemes:

[image]

I wrote 2 Linq queries against those tables - one of them using join like this:

```
var result = (from emailTemplate in _context.EmailTemplates.Include(et => et.EmailTemplateContents)
              join priorityLookup in _context.Lookups on new { GroupKey = "PRIORITIES", DetailKey = emailTemplate.Priority, emailTemplate.CompanyId } equals new { priorityLookup.GroupKey, priorityLookup.DetailKey, priorityLookup.CompanyId }
              join statusLookup in _context.Lookups on new { GroupKey = "STATUSES", DetailKey = emailTemplate.StatusCode, emailTemplate.CompanyId } equals new { statusLookup.GroupKey, statusLookup.DetailKey, statusLookup.CompanyId }
              join priorityLookupLabel in _context.LookupLabels on new { Locale = 1033, priorityLookup.DetailKey, priorityLookup.CompanyId } equals new { priorityLookupLabel.Locale, priorityLookupLabel.DetailKey, priorityLookupLabel.CompanyId }
              join statusLookupLabel in _context.LookupLabels on new { Locale = 1033, statusLookup.DetailKey, statusLookup.CompanyId } equals new { statusLookupLabel.Locale, statusLookupLabel.DetailKey, statusLookupLabel.CompanyId }
              where emailTemplate.CompanyId == 3
              select new EmailTemplateModel
                      {
                          Code = emailTemplate.Code,
                          TemplateName = emailTemplate.TemplateName,
                          FromEmail = emailTemplate.FromEmail,
                          BccEmail = emailTemplate.BccEmail,
                          CcEmail = emailTemplate.CcEmail,
                          PriorityCode = emailTemplate.Priority,
                          Priority = priorityLookupLabel.Label,
                          Subject = emailTemplate.EmailTemplateContents.Subject,
                          Body = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(emailTemplate.EmailTemplateContents.Body),
                          StatusCode = emailTemplate.StatusCode,
                          Status = statusLookupLabel.Label,
                          ToEmail = emailTemplate.ToEmail,
                          TriggerSqlCommand = emailTemplate.TriggerSqlCommand,
                          TriggerType = emailTemplate.TriggerType,
                          ModifDate = emailTemplate.ModifDate
                      }).ToList();
```

and one of them using `.Include` like so :

```
var results = _context.EmailTemplates
                      .Where(e => e.CompanyId == 3)
                      .Include(e => e.EmailTemplateContents)
                      .Include(e => e.Lookups)
                        .ThenInclude(g => g.LookupLabels)
                      .Include(e => e.LookupsNavigation)
                        .ThenInclude(g => g.LookupLabels)
                      .Select(e => new EmailTemplateModel
                                   {
                                       Code = e.Code,
                                       TemplateName = e.TemplateName,
                                       FromEmail = e.FromEmail,
                                       BccEmail = e.BccEmail,
                                       CcEmail = e.CcEmail,
                                       PriorityCode = e.Priority,
                                       PriorityLabel = e.Lookups.LookupLabels.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Locale == 1033),
                                       Subject = e.EmailTemplateContents.Subject,
                                       Body = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(e.EmailTemplateContents.Body),
                                       StatusCode = e.StatusCode,
                                       StatusLabel = e.LookupsNavigation.LookupLabels.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Locale == 1033),
                                       ToEmail = e.ToEmail,
                                       TriggerSqlCommand = e.TriggerSqlCommand,
                                       TriggerType = e.TriggerType,
                                       ModifDate = e.ModifDate
                                   }).ToList();
```

I tried to understand if there is any performance difference between these two type, so I checked the query generated by EF using profiler.

The SQL Script generated from the Join statement is :

```
SELECT 
    [e].[Code], [e].[TemplateName], [e].[FromEmail], [e].[BccEmail], 
    [e].[CcEmail], [e].[Priority], [l1].[Label], 
    [e0].[Subject], [e0].[Body], [e].[StatusCode], [l2].[Label], 
    [e].[ToEmail], [e].[TriggerSqlCommand], [e].[TriggerType], 
    [e].[ModifDate]
FROM [EmailTemplates] AS [e]
INNER JOIN [Lookups] AS [l] ON (('PRIORITIES' = [l].[GroupKey]) AND ([e].[Priority] = [l].[DetailKey])) AND ([e].[CompanyId] = [l].[CompanyId])
INNER JOIN [Lookups] AS [l0] ON (('STATUSES' = [l0].[GroupKey]) AND ([e].[StatusCode] = [l0].[DetailKey])) AND ([e].[CompanyId] = [l0].[CompanyId])
INNER JOIN [LookupLabels] AS [l1] ON ((1033 = [l1].[Locale]) AND ([l].[DetailKey] = [l1].[DetailKey])) AND ([l].[CompanyId] = [l1].[CompanyId])
INNER JOIN [LookupLabels] AS [l2] ON ((1033 = [l2].[Locale]) AND ([l0].[DetailKey] = [l2].[DetailKey])) AND ([l0].[CompanyId] = [l2].[CompanyId])
LEFT JOIN [EmailTemplateContents] AS [e0] ON ([e].[CompanyId] = [e0].[CompanyId]) AND ([e].[Code] = [e0].[EmailTemplateCode])
WHERE [e].[CompanyId] = 3
```

The SQL script generated from the `.Include` statement is :

```
SELECT 
    [e].[Code], [e].[TemplateName], [e].[FromEmail], [e].[BccEmail], 
    [e].[CcEmail], [e].[Priority], [t0].[DetailKey], [t0].[CompanyId], 
    [t0].[Locale], [t0].[Label], [t0].[OrderNo], [e0].[Subject], [e0].[Body], 
    [e].[StatusCode], [t2].[DetailKey], [t2].[CompanyId], [t2].[Locale], 
    [t2].[Label], [t2].[OrderNo], [e].[ToEmail], [e].[TriggerSqlCommand], 
    [e].[TriggerType], [e].[ModifDate]
FROM [EmailTemplates] AS [e]
INNER JOIN [Lookups] AS [l] ON ([e].[Priority] = [l].[DetailKey]) AND ([e].[CompanyId] = [l].[CompanyId])
LEFT JOIN [EmailTemplateContents] AS [e0] ON ([e].[CompanyId] = [e0].[CompanyId]) AND ([e].[Code] = [e0].[EmailTemplateCode])
INNER JOIN [Lookups] AS [l0] ON ([e].[StatusCode] = [l0].[DetailKey]) AND ([e].[CompanyId] = [l0].[CompanyId])
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [t].[DetailKey], [t].[CompanyId], [t].[Locale], [t].[Label], [t].[OrderNo]
    FROM (
        SELECT [l1].[DetailKey], [l1].[CompanyId], [l1].[Locale], [l1].[Label], [l1].[OrderNo], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [l1].[DetailKey], [l1].[CompanyId] ORDER BY [l1].[DetailKey], [l1].[CompanyId], [l1].[Locale]) AS [row]
        FROM [LookupLabels] AS [l1]
        WHERE [l1].[Locale] = 1033
    ) AS [t]
    WHERE [t].[row] <= 1
) AS [t0] ON ([l].[DetailKey] = [t0].[DetailKey]) AND ([l].[CompanyId] = [t0].[CompanyId])
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT [t1].[DetailKey], [t1].[CompanyId], [t1].[Locale], [t1].[Label], [t1].[OrderNo]
    FROM (
        SELECT [l2].[DetailKey], [l2].[CompanyId], [l2].[Locale], [l2].[Label], [l2].[OrderNo], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [l2].[DetailKey], [l2].[CompanyId] ORDER BY [l2].[DetailKey], [l2].[CompanyId], [l2].[Locale]) AS [row]
        FROM [LookupLabels] AS [l2]
        WHERE [l2].[Locale] = 1033
    ) AS [t1]
    WHERE [t1].[row] <= 1
) AS [t2] ON ([l0].[DetailKey] = [t2].[DetailKey]) AND ([l0].[CompanyId] = [t2].[CompanyId])
WHERE [e].[CompanyId] = 3
```

I compared the actual execution plans for both to see what the difference between these two is.

Here is the join execution plan:

[image: Join Actual Execution Plan]

and here is the include execution plan:

[image: Include Actual Execution Plan]

The cost of both queries are the same 50%.

Now I have couple of questions :

1. Based on the query cost(50%) should I consider these two equal performance-wise ?
2. Is there any suggestion for using include or join to make one of them faster or with fewer cost?
3. What are the pros and cons of using Join (Syntax/maintenance)?
4. What are the pros and cons of using Include (Syntax/maintenance)?
5. Which one should I use if the table has a few records or if it has lots of records?

Comment: As far as i remember, you don't need all the `Include`'s in the second one since you are already selecting the properties. Not sure that it will generate the same SQL though.

Comment: Also not sure that both queries will always generate the same results since the first one uses more constraints on joins than second one (see `priorityLookup` and `statusLookup` in the first one).

Comment: thanks for your comment since the EmailTemplate table has two foreign keys to the Lookup table I have 2 Navigation property I guess I should include both navigation property in order to get Child Values for each one of them am I right?

Comment: the results for both are identical the reason I used more constraints in the join statement is I don't want to use navigation property

Comment: I'm writing about `GroupKey = "PRIORITIES"` and `GroupKey = "STATUSES"` in the first version.

Comment: Looking at the complex syntax of join, if both give identical results with similar performance, I'd definitely go for Includes. The complex syntax gives chance for bugs to sneak in. I want to see what others have to say though.

Comment: How about removing all the `Include`s (which are not needed when `Select`-ing) from both and compare the queries and plans again? Then the real question would be manual joins vs navigation properties, and in EF (Core) the later should always be the preferred way (let EF do the joins for you).

Comment: thanks, @IvanStoev but what do you mean by removing `Include` s (which are not needed when `Select`-ing)?

Comment: Your queries are not returning entity instances, hence do not need `Include` / `ThenInclude` operators. Usually they are ignored, but I see some redundant `JOIN` in second query. So just remove all `Include` / `ThenInclude` from both LINQ queries.

Comment: @IvanStoev once I removed Include/ThenInclude from the second Linq query, the query costs increased to 55%

Comment: This is an old question but I had the same doubt. As far as I can see, the second SQL generated by EF Core, includes all the columns of the related entities in the result, so there is an increase of memory. On the other hand, the first SQL generated only includes the necessary columns (less memory consumption).